# Scheme mode function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to find the mode of a list

Assuming the list is sorted ascending order

Here is my mode function

```
 (define freq
   (lambda (l)
     (cond ((null? l)l)
           ((null? (cdr l))l)
           ((not(equal? (car l) (car(cdr l))))(freq(cdr(delete l (car l)))))
           (else (freq (cdr l)))
 )))

   (freq '(4 4 4 4 5 7 9 9 9)) => should returns 4 but its returning 9 instead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, which is similar to Óscar's solution but centralises the update of the longest/winning result in one place:

```
(define (longest-run lst)
  (let loop ((result #f)
             (cur #f)
             (count 0)
             (longest 0)
             (lst lst))
    (cond ((> count longest)
           (loop cur cur count count lst))
          ((null? lst) result)
          ((eqv? (car lst) cur)
           (loop result cur (+ count 1) longest (cdr lst)))
          (else
           (loop result (car lst) 1 longest (cdr lst))))))
```

I think my solution is shorter, cleaner, and less repetitive, but Óscar's solution has the advantage of updating the variables fewer times: his solution only updates the variables at the end of a run, whereas mine updates the variables whenever the current length is longer than the longest length seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

What's the logic behind your procedure? how do you expect it to find the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) by removing elements from the input list? you should be counting frequencies instead:

```
(define (mode lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f ; edge case: an empty list doesn't have a mode
      (let loop ((lst lst) ; list to traverse
                 (current (car lst)) ; current element in sequence
                 (counter 0) ; number of times current element appears
                 (max-current (car lst)) ; the mode
                 (max-counter 0)) ; number of times the mode appears
        (cond ((null? lst) ; the list is finished
               (if (> counter max-counter) current max-current))
              ((= (car lst) current) ; current element equal to previous
               (loop (cdr lst) ; add 1 to counter and keep iterating
                     current
                     (add1 counter)
                     max-current
                     max-counter))
              (else ; found a different element, a new sequence starts
               (loop (cdr lst)
                     (car lst) ; update current element
                     1
                     (if (> counter max-counter) current max-current)
                     (max counter max-counter)))))))
```

It works by keeping track of how many times each element appears, returning the element that appears most frequently - because by definition the mode is the value that appears most often in a set of data. We take advantage of the fact that the input list is sorted, because we know that a new sequence of repeated elements starts when the current element is different from the previous one we encountered.

Comment: Lopez How do i get the element though? for example: '(4 4 4 4 4 5 7 9 9 9) I want it to return 4

Comment: Lopez '(4 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 9 9 9) I want this to return a 4

Comment: @user3100209 I rewrote my answer, there was a bug in the original procedure. See the explanation