# scheme mode"list" function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to find the most repeated element in a list. The problem is I have to use the `count` function, which finds how many time a specific value is repeated in a list (for example, `(count 7 '(4 8 9 2 4 8 9))` => 0, `(count 2 '(4 8 9 2 2 4 8 9 2))` => 3).
I finished the `count` function and I think I'm close with the `mode` function. Any help will be appreciated.

```
(define (count item list)
  (cond
    [(null? list) '()]
    [(= item (car list)) (+ 1 (count item (cdr list)))]
    [#t (count item (cdr list))]))

(define (mode lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) '()]
    [(> (count (car lst) lst) (mode (cdr lst))) (car lst)]
    [else (mode (cdr lst))]))
```

Comment: The `count` function isn't right. Did you _test_ it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`mode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) night, as it seems - check a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208889/), which uses a different approach: it assumes that the input list is sorted. But of course - the `mode` procedure can be implemented in terms of `count` with a non-sorted input list, although less efficiently - it's an `O(n^2)` solution:

```
(define (mode lnum)
  (let loop ((lst lnum)         ; list to traverse
             (max-counter 0)    ; number of times the mode appears
             (max-current #f))  ; the mode
    (if (null? lst)             ; if the list is empty
        max-current             ; return the mode
        (let ((n (count (car lst) lnum))) ; # of times current element appears
          (if (> n max-counter) ; if it appears more times
              (loop (cdr lst) n (car lst)) ; then we found a new maximum
              (loop (cdr lst) max-counter max-current)))))) ; else continue
```

The idea is simple, count how many times is each element in the list, and keep track of the element which appears the most.

And FYI, neither this nor the other linked solutions (which require that a sort is performed before) implement the most efficient algorithm for finding a mode in an unsorted list. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128413/201359), the `most-common` procedure implemented there also computes the mode of a list, but in `O(n)`.

Comment: I saw it, but unfortunately I'm forced to use count function to solve this problem